# Filling Javascript array from PHP request

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to fill a JavaScript array with results from my PHP query to database. I have initially filled it with variables but i wanna get those from database . I am putting the query result the 'liste' variable, I don't know if I can use foreach to fill it, any help would be appreciated thanks.

PHP code:

`````
<?php
        $sql="SELECT * FROM  produits WHERE cat='Interieur'";
        $req=$db->prepare($sql);
        $req->execute();
        $liste=$req->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
?>

<?php foreach ($liste as $product): ?> ````
`````

Javascript code:

```
var arrayTitle = ["Chaise Skandinave", "Chaise2", "Chaise3","Table1","Table2","Table3","Fauteuil1","Fauteuil2","Fauteuil3"];
var arrayImage = ["images/ChaiseSkandinave.jpg", "images/Chaise2.jpg", "images/Chaise3.jpg","images/Table1.jpg","images/Table2.jpg","images/Table3.jpg","images/Fauteuil1.jpg","images/Fauteuil2.jpg","images/Fauteuil3.jpg"];
var arrayDesc = ["a", "b", "c","d","e","f","g","h","i"];
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

function openModal(i)
{
    modal.style.display = "block";

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
            document.getElementsByClassName("modalimg")[0].src = arrayImage[i];
            document.getElementsByClassName("modaltitle")[0].innerHTML = arrayTitle[i];
            document.getElementsByClassName("modaldesc")[0].innerHTML = arrayDesc[i];
    });
}
```

HTML CODE:

```
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row animate-box">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center fh5co-heading">
                    <span>Meubles Interieurs</span>
                    <h2>Produits</h2>
                    <p></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" id="row1">
            </div>
            <?php
            $sql="SELECT * FROM  produits WHERE cat='Interieur'";
            $req=$db->prepare($sql);
            $req->execute();
            $liste=$req->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            ?>
            <?php foreach ($liste as $product): ?>

                <div class="col-md-4 text-center animate-box">
                <div class="product">
                    <div class="product-grid" style="background-image:url(images/<?php echo $product->num; ?>.jpg)">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <p>
                                <a href="single.html" class="icon"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
                                <a href="javascript:openModal()" class="icon"><i class="icon-eye"></i></a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="desc">
                        <h3><a href="single.html"><?php echo $product->nom; ?> </a></h3>
                        <span class="price"><?php echo number_format($product->prix,2,',',''); ?> TND</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>

            <?php endforeach ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you show your html code ?

Comment: A little strong than that, can you show your [mcve]?

Comment: i have added the html code matey ;)

Comment: @Mike Pomax what do you mean by minimal,complete and verifiable example ? it's a projet and i have a list of products to display in frontend , each product has a button that on click triggers a JS modal , the JS modal reads from the array so i need it to be dynamic to match the product details you see ? i hope this helps.

Comment: What do _you_ mean? The link to the stackoverflow policy article is pretty clear on what it means, and the onus is on your to take your code, copy it into a new directory, delete everything that isn't directly related, and then end up with two or three files _at most_ (but 99% of the time, a single file with a single function) that show off this problem. That's not just somehting you do "for us", that's an _important debugging skill to have_ because it almost _always_ lets you discover the problem entirely on your own, as part of the "reducing until it can't be reduced any further" exercise.